# Открыть программу на клиентской машине из delphi программы на rdp

Tags: delphi, rdp

Клиенты работают в delphi-приложении с удалённого рабочего стола. Нужно из этой программы запустить видеофайл именно на клиентском компьютере. Сам файл также находится на клиентском компьютере. Выглядеть должно так: пользователь на терминале в программе нажимает на кнопку "Открыть файл", и уже на его компьютере открывается этот файл.
Можно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: нет, нельзя такое реализовать

Comment: конечно можно. Только нужно написать приложение-сервер и дописать клиентскую программу. И установить на всех клиентских компьютерах программу приложение-сервер.